# Is there an in-game scoreboard on console?

Tags: overwatch

I'm playing Overwatch on a PlayStation 4 and I haven't found any sort of keybinding in the options to bring up a scoreboard during the game, but I have found references to a tab-screen in [other questions on the site](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/264759/so-im-on-fire-so-what).

Is there in fact an in-game scoreboard I can bring up during the match?

If I attempt to change a hero while reviving I noticed I can see the current composition of my team, but this screen doesn't seem like a scoreboard to me. Are people talking about a different screen when they mention the tab-screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Is there in fact an in-game scoreboard I can bring up during the match?

No, there's is not. In fact Jeff Kaplan himself has stated in an [interview](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/the-story-of-overwatch-the-complete-jeff-kaplan-in/1100-6439202/):

> So we we basically stopped displaying any form of scores, kills, deaths because it really wasn't telling the story of who was doing their job properly to win or lose as a team. And really, what it's all about is, "Did you win or lose as a team?" None of that other stuff really matters at the end of the day.

You have some form of knowing if you were one of the top performers of the game by the medals and upvotes you get.
You can also view your performance in the "Tab Menu" or tab-screen. See the next section.

---

## Are people talking about a different screen when they mention the tab-screen?

The tab-screen is not the hero select screen. Here's an example of a tab-screen:

[image: Tab Menu]

As you can see there are some of your stats there that you can check but you can't compare them against any other player. As I've explained in the previous section, this is intentional to promote team play.

---

## Bonus

During development, Overwatch had indeed a scoreboard that has since been long removed.
The scoreboard used to look like this:
[image: Old Overwatch scoreboard]

Comment: The tab screen looks like what I'm looking for (so I don't have to enter/cancel the hero select screen to keep up with my team's comp).  Do you know how to access that screen on PS4?  Or is it a PC-only feature?

Comment: I'm not sure. I can test out the PS4 version tomorrow. Have you tried the "weird buttons" like th d-pad, L3 and R3?

Comment: It's the big touchpad button in the center.

Answer (score 3):

There is no Real Scoreboard in Overwatch where u can see how well your Team performs

The Screen with the Team Composition is that what you want

You can see there who is on Fire and below that are your stats