# What do the numbers when destroying non-player things mean?

Tags: overwatch

When you destroy an enemy object that isnt a player, such as DVA's suit or Torbjorn's turret, you will see +### message. What do the numbers mean? Do they actually affect anything? As far as I understand there is no points system.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269962/how-can-i-stay-on-fire for threshold of fireriness.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just like when eliminating players, the number is the amount added to your [On-Fire Meter](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/On-fire_Meter). It has no gameplay purpose other than letting yourself and everyone else know you're doing particularly well when you reach a certain threshold. See also [I'm on fire. So?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/264759/im-on-fire-so)

Comment: Thanks. Any clue what the thresholds are for onfire/max bar?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg The threshold for being on fire is 250 fire points. The points decay at a rate of 5 per second, and the meter visually caps at 350 points. However, you can gain unlimited fire points, and the meter won't start ticking down until you're at 350 or lower.

Answer (score 5):

All the numbers are how much "fire" you get. The blue bar beneath your health is the fire meter, and if it's above a certain threshold then you are "on fire". It drains over time, and every time you see one of those numbers pop up it fills back up that amount.

Comment: Thanks. Any clue what the thresholds are for onfire/max bar?