# What do the numbers next to the flame represent?

Tags: overwatch

When you get an elimination the message that pops up has a number and a flame at the end. I assume that it has something to do with being "On Fire", but what exactly are the numbers tracking?

[image: Example]

Comment: see http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269868/what-do-the-numbers-when-destroying-non-player-things-mean/269870#269870 and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269962/how-can-i-stay-on-fire

Comment: @Dragonrage Thanks. I tried searching, but I guess I wasn't using the right keywords.